# How to remove an org-mode entry's effort property while viewing the agenda?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is there any way to completely delete an entry's effort property from within the org-mode agenda?

Ideally, I'd also like to be able to bulk remove efforts from the agenda view.

"org-agenda-set-effort" doesn't provide a method to remove the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three parts to the answer:

- write a function that deletes an `Effort` entry from the properties drawer of the current headline.
- write the corresponding `agenda` function that calls the function above "remotely"; i.e. you call the agenda function in the agenda and it in turn switches context to the headline in the file and calls the first function above.
- add an entry for the `agenda` function to `org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions`, consisting of the character that you use to call the agenda function and the *symbol* corresponding to the name of the function.

There are plenty of examples of remote functions in the Org mode sources, so I just copied the code from the `org-agenda-set-effort` function and changed the local function that it calls, to come up with the following code (seems to work; very lightly tested):

```el
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer

(defun org-delete-effort ()
   (interactive)
   (org-entry-delete (point) org-effort-property))


 (defun org-agenda-delete-effort ()
    "Set the effort property for the current headline."
    (interactive)
    (org-agenda-check-no-diary)
    (org-agenda-maybe-loop
       #'org-agenda-delete-effort nil nil nil
       (let* ((hdmarker (or (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker)
                            (org-agenda-error)))
              (buffer (marker-buffer hdmarker))
              (pos (marker-position hdmarker))
              (inhibit-read-only t)
              newhead)
         (org-with-remote-undo buffer
           (with-current-buffer buffer
             (widen)
             (goto-char pos)
             (org-show-context 'agenda)
             (call-interactively 'org-delete-effort)
             (end-of-line 1)
             (setq newhead (org-get-heading)))
         (org-agenda-change-all-lines newhead hdmarker)))))


(add-to-list 'org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions
             '(?Y org-agenda-delete-effort))

#+end_src
```

So you mark the entries in the agenda, then do `B Y` to delete efforts. I chose `Y` as the character to call the function because it was not being used for any other bulk operation (in my case - YMMV).

This can obviously be used as a template for other such remote operations.

Comment: This code is working perfectly for me. I also bound a key so that I can call org-agenda-delete-effort on individual items from the agenda view.

Comment: Not sure whether you can edit the answer (you probably need more reputation), but if you add a comment with what you did, I will edit the answer to add that information.

Comment: I simply added a keybinding for your org-agenda-delete-effort function which also allows it to be called on individual items within the agenda view, versus using the bulk command. 

`(eval-after-load "org-agenda-mode" 'my/after-load-org-agenda-mode)

(defun my/after-load-org-agenda-mode ()
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "c E") 'org-agenda-delete-effort)))`

Comment: Oh, I misread: but do you need a separate keydef for that? Doesn't `B Y` work on the item you are on if you have not marked any entries?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `B Y` does work, so a separate key binding is redundant. All these years and I had no idea that you could run a bulk action on an unmarked agenda item. Thank you, that is incredibly useful.