# "not allowed in tags-type agenda buffer or component"

Tags: org-agenda

One of my agenda views shows all past timestamped items (not scheduled or deadlines). I would want to from that view, select them all and move them to the current date. I noticed that I can't do this because I get the following error:

```
not allowed in tags-type agenda buffer or component
```

I am using the view of filtering by tags (`org-agenda` and then `m`), then I filter using `"TIMESTAMP<"<today>""` and then I get my list of entries. I can't seem to operate on them using the usual org-agenda commands.

The error I get is as follows when I try to move one of the items to the following day by using `S-<right>`:

```el
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Not allowed in ’tags’-type agenda buffer or compon...")
      signal(error ("Not allowed in ’tags’-type agenda buffer or compon..."))
      error("Not allowed in '%s'-type agenda buffer or component" tags)
      org-agenda-check-type(t agenda)
      org-agenda-date-later(1)
      org-agenda-do-date-later(nil)
      funcall-interactively(org-agenda-do-date-later nil)
      call-interactively(org-agenda-do-date-later nil nil)
      command-execute(org-agenda-do-date-later)
```

Comment: How are you trying to move them to the current date?

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to t, try it again and add the backtrace to the question.

Comment: I am using the view of filtering by tags (org-agenda and then "m"), then I filter using         "TIMESTAMP<"<today>"" and then I get my list of entries. I can't seem to operate on them using the usual org-agenda commands.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the error I get when debug-on-error is on. Thanks.

Comment: I copied the third comment above into your question. Please make sure that the question contains *all* the important information. It should stand on its own even if all the comments are deleted. That's a general rule for all your questions. But this question now looks good to me.

Comment: I changed the key sequence to `S-<right>` after a bit of experimentation: please use standard descriptions of key sequences - see [User input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html) and pointers therein in the Emacs manual.

Comment: See [this question/answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63912/how-to-remove-an-org-mode-entrys-effort-property-while-viewing-the-agenda/63923#63923). It is not a duplicate but it shows  an outline of what you would have to do to implement a bulk operation that would work on the agenda - but there are probably some gotchas because you want to do the operation on a matching-query agenda, not on the daily/weekly/monthly agenda.

Comment: BTW, just in case it is not clear: `org-agenda-date-later` only works on the daily/weekly./.. agenda (thatt's what the call to `org-agenda-check-type` does in your backtrace), so you would probably have to implement a variant of that in order to make it work from a matching-query agenda.

Comment: I understand, and I see now that it is impossible to move the dates or do bulk actions in this view.

Comment: You *can* do bulk actions: mark a few entries with `m`, then press `B`. One of the options is `f` to call your own function, but you have to write that function.